# HTTP Referrer is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a .NET main page it can be reached using other .NET pages so based on the last page I will do something on this page.

But when I try to read what is my last page it gives null; but its not supposed to give like that.

Here is my code:

```
Uri ref = Request.UrlReferrer;
string lastpage = ref.ToString();
```

Comment: Is this ASP.net web forms?  Is your code in a code behind file?

Comment: @BenRobinson yes asp.net webforms

Comment: I would like to know why I am downvoted I don't see I have violated any rules of this community!

Comment: It's too board for us to help you. Try to limit the scope first. https://www.google.com/search?q=Request.UrlReferrer+is+null&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also faced this problem in my case the problem was **response.redirect**

### Possible reasons

1. `URLReferrer` doesn't work with `Redirects`
2. Remember its http_referrer not https_referrer so if your previous page is Https URLReferrer doesn't work
3. Setting in browser may prevent from sending the data
4. Some security software behind proxy server or firewall may strip away the referrer information

### Suggestions

1. Try using `hyperlinks`
2. Try using `cross page posting`
3. This problem can be solved by adding refpage name in `querystring` with redirect url

   ```
    Response.Redirect("mainpage.aspx?prevpage=pagename.aspx");
   ```
4. Storing the ref page name in a `session` and check in the main page

   ```
   Session["PREVPAGE"] = "pagename.aspx";
   ```
5. You can replace `response.redirect` with `server.transfer` and use the following code

`this.Page.PreviousPage` in your main page but beware the URL won't change in browser address bar

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer in my case also the response.redirect is the culprit

Answer (score 3):

The referrer relies on the browser to send the information.  It's also possible you won't get a referrer if the URL is typed directly in, or pulled from a favorite.  If this is the case, your `ref` variable will be null, and the second line will throw a `NullReferenceException`.  You need to check for null.

Comment: You can also disable sending referrer information in some browsers.

Comment: I am using development environment only and I have not disabled it in browser